# Ignore characters "" in string

Tags: c#, string, special-characters

I want to have a program that will be able to write to the file:

```
addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum]["channel"][serverChannel]["ip"]
```

, but must ignore the characters "" in the text

My restult: Visual studio does not ignores characters "" in string and wants strings like IP etc.. thx for help

Sry for my english

There is my Program:

```
 string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+ "logininfo.py";

    string[] lines = {
    "import serverInfo"
    , "serverNum=1"
    , "serverChannel=1"
    , "addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum]["channel"][serverChannel]["ip"]"};

System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path);
file.WriteLine(lines);

file.Close();
```

I almost forgot I want more lines, this program is trimmed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can escape those characters with a slash:

```
string[] lines = {
    " import serverInfo" ,
    "serverNum=1" ,
    "serverChannel=1" ,
    "addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum][\"channel\"][serverChannel][\"ip\"] "};
```

or use a [@-quoted string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and use `""` instead of `"` like so:

```
string[] lines = {
    " import serverInfo" ,
    "serverNum=1" ,
    "serverChannel=1" ,
    @"addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum][""channel""][serverChannel][""ip""] "};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [concatenate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation) the strings:

```
"addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum][" + channel + "][serverChannel][" + ip + "]"};
```

Or if you wish for "channel" to be used as a string value, use single quotes:

```
"addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum]['channel'][serverChannel]['ip']"};
```

Comment: I don´t want to use channel etc.. I want to write to file this line:
 addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum]["channel"][serverChannel]["ip"]

Comment: @user1849432 I couldn't understand the question correctly. I've updated my answer, I believe you either need to escape the characters, or use single quotes so as not to confuse the script.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special characters

```
"addr_new = serverInfo.REGION_DICT[0][serverNum][\"channel\"][serverChannel][\"ip\"]"
```